# Referencing model attributes within form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am hoping to edit multiple models at the same time on a singe page. Rather than using formsets, I got this to work with an array of forms that I loop through in the template in the view:

```
{% extends 'app_base.html' %} {% block content %}
<p>{{message}}</p>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %} {% for form in forms %}{{ form.as_p }}{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

However, annoying, I cannot see what I am editing in the output as its just a bunch of text boxes without labels.

As such, is there any way to access the model attributes alongside the form as I loop through like:

```
{% for form in forms %}{{form.object.name}}: {{ form.as_p }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is your form a `ModelForm`? If so, `form.instance` is the `instance` that's being updated, assuming you initialised each form with an `instance`.

Comment: Great @dirkgroten, works like a charm. Can you write an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `ModelForm` for all your forms, you need to initialise it with the model instance that's being updated (`MyForm(data=request.POST, instance=...)`).

You can access the `instance` of the form, it's just an attribute on the form: `form.instance`.

Note that it's always present on the `ModelForm`, even if you don't pass an `instance` when initialising. In that case it's an initialised, not saved, instance of the model of your form. So `form.instance.pk = None` in that case.